# ANSI to Unicode or backward conversion: how is it possible to do?

Tags: c++, unicode, ansi

There are several functions that convert ANSI to Unicode and vice versa. Here are those functions `WideCharToMultiByte`, `MultiByteToWideChar`, `A2W`, `W2A`.

Now I don't understand how `A2W` and `W2A` work. **The thing is that when you convert something to another thing than you should have two sets set `A` and set `B` so that each element in set `A` is mapped to one and only one element in set `B` uniquely.** Regarding this there are several problems:

1. ANSI is one byte and UNICODE is at least 2 byte which means not all elements in UNICODE set can be mapped to ANSI uniquely.
2. Set `ANSI` and set `Unicode` are not strictly defined. I mean there are different encoding for both.

Hereby, my question: how we can convert them and be sure that we have not spoiled the data?

Comment: 1. 'ANSI' and 'Unicode' aren't encodings. 2. The conversion API has to tell you everything went okay. (Or, I suppose, you could round trip and compare.)

Comment: There is no character set properly called "ANSI". The [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) code page and its relatives are often *incorrectly* called ANSI; see the linked Wikipedia article for details. And in Windows, the name "Unicode" is commonly used to refer to UTF-16, which is merely one of several *representations* of Unicode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have mentioned, there is no such character set as 'ANSI'. Unfortunately, the Windows API refers to `CP_ACP`, the 'ANSI code page', which refers to one of several character sets depending on which non-unicode locale is selected on your machine.

That said, with regards to your original question, no, you cannot always round trip between `CP_ACP` and a unicode encoding. There's no equivalent for あ in `CP_ACP` on an English-locale windows system, for example.

When this happens, `WideCharToMultiByte` will replace the character that has no equivalent with `lpDefaultChar`, if set, and set `*lpUsedDefaultChar` to true. You can pass a pointer to a boolean variable in `lpUsedDefaultChar` and check it after calling to see if your string contained non-translatable characters. The other direction, `MultiByteToWideChar` never fails as long as the input is valid in your local codepage, however. To try to detect invalid text, pass in the `MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS` flag and check for an error - that said, just because the text is in some other codepage, doesn't mean you'll get an error from it (it's hard to tell if the text is actually invalid, or if it's merely gibberish).

Comment: This means that where I use W2A conversion I should be sure that all characters are from the range of `char` only they are represented by two bytes?

Comment: @Narek, no, that only works in certain single-byte codepages where the lower 256 codepoints are mapped directly to the same-numbered unicode codepoints. In shift-jis, for example, there are codepoints between U+0000 and U+00FF that are not representable (notably, U+005F `~` and U+005C \, but most above U+0080 as well).

Answer (score 1):

Do a roundtrip conversion, then compare the result to the original.

You can probably invoke the conversion functions so they throw an error for an undefined result, if you prefer.